# Why is init() not called on filters within FilterChainProxy in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have configured my own filter to be part of `FilterChainProxy` in spring security. I was surprised that `init()` method (implemented from `Filter` interface) is not being called on this filter. When I moved the filter out of the `FilterChainProxy` to the main chain the `init()` method is called as expected

Does `FilterChainProxy` treat its filters differently?

One Boot note:

I had to provide `FilterRegistrationBean` with `enabled=false` to avoid registration to the main filter chain but I don't believe this is the cause as I have seen the behaviour in non-boot applicaitons.

Comment: No, it doesn't call the init methods. See the [Filter Lifecycle](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.html) section in the class Javadoc.

Comment: This answers my question, thank you. If you wanna make it an answer I would accept it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `FilterChainProxy` doesnt invoke the init() and destroy() methods. But for me it was a necessity so i used `DelegatingFilterProxy`, it does have a way to alter this via the "targetFilterLifecycle" property, when it's set to true. This way the init() and destroy() will be invoked as usual. Read more here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html